# Border at corner only in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, user-interface

I trying to make border at corner only in container.

```
Container(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0, left: 8.0),
  height: 60,
  child: Card(
    elevation: 2,
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        side: BorderSide(color: appThemeColor.shade200, width: 0.5),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
    child: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topRight: Radius.circular(15),
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(15)),
            color: Colors.deepPurple,
          ),
          width: 5,
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
)
```

[image]

Comment: Let me clarify a bit. You want painted corners like on image?

Comment: @SimonSot just need painted corner.

Comment: I get it. This is easily done with `CustomPaint` widget. Do you want me to code it for you?

Comment: @SimonSot yes, i don't have much knowledge of custom paint.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This can be done with [`CustomPaint`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomPaint-class.html) widget with  CustomPainter set as `foregroundPainter`:

```dart
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'CustomPaint spotlight',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('CustomPaint spotlight'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: CustomPaint(
            foregroundPainter: BorderPainter(),
            child: Container(
              width: 200,
              height: 100,
              color: Colors.deepOrange[50],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BorderPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    double sh = size.height; // for convenient shortage
    double sw = size.width; // for convenient shortage
    double cornerSide = sh * 0.1; // desirable value for corners side

    Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.black
      ..strokeWidth = 1.5
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round;

    Path path = Path()
      ..moveTo(cornerSide, 0)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(0, 0, 0, cornerSide)
      ..moveTo(0, sh - cornerSide)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(0, sh, cornerSide, sh)
      ..moveTo(sw - cornerSide, sh)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(sw, sh, sw, sh - cornerSide)
      ..moveTo(sw, cornerSide)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(sw, 0, sw - cornerSide, 0);

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(BorderPainter oldDelegate) => false;

  @override
  bool shouldRebuildSemantics(BorderPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

This produces the result like:

[image]

You need to know that CustomPaint does not crop its child corners and in some cases that might be discouraging. You have two ways of solving this:

- Easy one - to cast rounded borders on its child and make them be visibly equal to CustomPaint borders.
- Robust one - to wrap child with [`ClipPath`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ClipPath-class.html) with a path that copies CustomPaint path

```dart
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'CustomPaint spotlight',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('CustomPaint spotlight'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: CustomPaint(
            foregroundPainter: BorderPainter(),
            child: ClipPath(
              clipper: BorderClipper(),
              child: Container(
                width: 200,
                height: 100,
                color: Colors.deepOrange[50],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BorderPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    double sh = size.height; // for convenient shortage
    double sw = size.width; // for convenient shortage
    double cornerSide = sh * 0.1; // desirable value for corners side

    Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.black
      ..strokeWidth = 1.5
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round;

    Path path = Path()
      ..moveTo(cornerSide, 0)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(0, 0, 0, cornerSide)
      ..moveTo(0, sh - cornerSide)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(0, sh, cornerSide, sh)
      ..moveTo(sw - cornerSide, sh)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(sw, sh, sw, sh - cornerSide)
      ..moveTo(sw, cornerSide)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(sw, 0, sw - cornerSide, 0);

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(BorderPainter oldDelegate) => false;

  @override
  bool shouldRebuildSemantics(BorderPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}

class BorderClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    double sh = size.height; // for convenient shortage
    double sw = size.width; // for convenient shortage
    double cornerSide = sh * 0.1;

    Path path = Path()
      ..moveTo(cornerSide, 0)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(0, 0, 0, cornerSide)
      ..moveTo(0, sh - cornerSide)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(0, sh, cornerSide, sh)
      ..moveTo(sw - cornerSide, sh)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(sw, sh, sw, sh - cornerSide)
      ..moveTo(sw, cornerSide)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(sw, 0, sw - cornerSide, 0);
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! for your answer.

Comment: This is really helpful. But could u tell me how to reduce the curvature of those borders? Tried changing the values but still didn't change much. I'm looking for something equivalent to the curvature of a `borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4)`

Comment: @HarshanaRathnayaka if I understood you right then for this case you can:
a) change the point x1, y1 in quadraticBezierTo func, through which it calculates its curvature
b) but I assume just this will not solve you the problem because your corners will be curved right from the start (if thats what you want - just adjust them as well to look more natural) OR you will have to split each curve here on two straight lines (lineTo)(at start and in the end) and quadraticBezierTo between them

Answer (score 0):

[@simon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13701546/simon-sot)

Thanks for the answer on this one! really helped me. I wanted to just enrich it for the use case I had.

Expanded on constructor to allow for color change width etc.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:app/shared/utils.dart';

class BorderPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final Color color;
  final double strokeWidth;
  final StrokeCap strokeCap;

  BorderPainter({this.color = Colors.black, this.strokeWidth = 1.5, this.strokeCap = StrokeCap.round});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    double sh = size.height; // for convenient shortage
    double cornerSide = sh * 0.1; // desirable value for corners side

    Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = color
      ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round;

    Path path = getBezierPath(cornerSide, sh, size.width);

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(BorderPainter oldDelegate) => false;

  @override
  bool shouldRebuildSemantics(BorderPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

Created a Util function so not to repeat the moveTo and quadraticBezierTo

```
Path getBezierPath(double cornerSide, double sideHeight, double sideWidth) {
  return Path()
    ..moveTo(cornerSide, 0)
    ..quadraticBezierTo(0, 0, 0, cornerSide)
    ..moveTo(0, sideHeight - cornerSide)
    ..quadraticBezierTo(0, sideHeight, cornerSide, sideHeight)
    ..moveTo(sideWidth - cornerSide, sideHeight)
    ..quadraticBezierTo(sideWidth, sideHeight, sideWidth, sideHeight - cornerSide)
    ..moveTo(sideWidth, cornerSide)
    ..quadraticBezierTo(sideWidth, 0, sideWidth - cornerSide, 0);
}
```